# (Done) Reopen question about no longer working weekends

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Manager is mad that I can no longer work on weekends for family reasons](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186969/manager-is-mad-that-i-can-no-longer-work-on-weekends-for-family-reasons) should clearly be reopened.

"How should I deal with this?" is easily a goal that we can address, in addition to being the exact phrase used by many (if not most) other questions.

The OP is clearly not asking for advice on a specific choice.

This question should not have been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the question and also think it is answerable and not asking for a specific choice.

It already had 3 reopen votes, so I went and cast a binding vote and opened it again.